# Callback when animations created dynamically finish

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, queue

I have the follwing code where I am adding effects from two loops inside queues:

```
tablaActual = ({
    1111: {
        titulo: "Nuevo Video 1",
        usuario: "RadioBot",
        alta: "1353182478"
    },
    2243: {
        titulo: "Old Boy Fashion",
        usuario: "RadioBot",
        alta: "1353182479"
    },
    3432: {
        titulo: "Britney spears",
        usuario: "RadioBot",
        alta: "1353182825"
    }
});

tablaNueva = ({
    1111: {
        titulo: "Nuevo Video 1",
        usuario: "RadioBot",
        alta: "1353182478"
    },
    1112: {
        titulo: "Nuevo video 2",
        usuario: "RadioBot",
        alta: "1353182477"
    },
    1113: {
        titulo: "Nuevo video 3",
        usuario: "RadioBot",
        alta: "1353182476"
    }
});


$("button").bind("click", function() {

    var body = $('body');

    retardation = 500;
    i = 1;

    // we delete the old ones that doesnt match in the new table
    $.each(tablaActual, function(index) {
        if (!tablaNueva[index]) {
            delay = i * retardation;

            $('#lista #id' + index).delay(delay).slideUp("normal", function() {
                $(this).remove();
            }).queue("cola1");

            delete tablaActual[index];
            i++;
        }
    });

    // we add the new ones that doesnt match in the old table
    $.each(tablaNueva, function(index, vars) {
        if (!tablaActual[index]) {

            delay = i * retardation;
            $('<tr id="id' + index + '"><td class="cancion"><h3>' + vars.titulo + '</h3></td><td class="autor">' + vars.usuario + '<span>' + vars.alta + '</span></td></tr>').appendTo('#lista').hide().delay(delay).show('slow').queue("cola2");


            tablaActual[index] = vars;
            i++;


        }
    });

    $("tr:animated").promise().done(function() {

        alert("done");
    });


});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dSGWx/7/)

When all the TR animations finish, it should trigger the alert, but I think I'm doing it wrong because the alert pops up as soon as I click the run button.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use jQuery.Deferred() to make it work. By doing this, you queue up a number of deferred objects that resolve once the corresponding item animation has finished.

In short, create an array of deferred objects and wait for them using the somewhat odd construct `jQuery.when.apply(...).done(function() { ... })`.

Take a look at [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dSGWx/9/).

Answer (score 0):

You could move your alert (finish callback) in the callback of the `show` function and test if all animations have been done : http://jsfiddle.net/dSGWx/12/

```
var totalmacth=0;
var loop=0;
// los que se tienen que añadir
$.each(tablaNueva, function(index, vars) {
    if (!tablaActual[index]) {
    totalmacth++;

    delay = i * retardation;
    $('<tr id="id' + index + '"><td class="cancion"><h3>' + vars.titulo + '</h3></td><td class="autor">' + vars.usuario + '<span>' + vars.alta + '</span></td></tr>').appendTo('#lista').hide().delay(delay)
         .show('slow',function(){
              loop++; 
              console.log(loop + ' ' + totalmacth)                
              if(loop === totalmacth)
                  alert("done");

          });
    tablaActual[index] = vars;
    i++;
    }      
});
```

Comment: I think mzedeler way is better, do you agree with this?

Comment: I do agree. My answer is the easy way to fix your problem, and @mzedeler's answer the neatest.